# why is the download in WKWebView is not working

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have a `webview` and on one site there is a button, that generates a pdf file and then starts a download. I have implemented the following methods:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, preferences: WKWebpagePreferences, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences) -> Void) {
    
    if navigationAction.shouldPerformDownload {
        decisionHandler(.download, preferences)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow, preferences)
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, didBecome download: WKDownload) {
    download.delegate = self
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, didBecome download: WKDownload) {
    download.delegate = self
}

func download(_ download: WKDownload, decideDestinationUsing response: URLResponse, suggestedFilename: String, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
    
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let url = dir.appendingPathComponent(suggestedFilename)
        completionHandler(url)
    }
    
}
```

But from these only the first is being called and enters the else-part. The others aren't called at all...
What could be the reason for that?

the console shows only

```
WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, domain=WebKitErrorDomain, code=102, isMainFrame=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It fallbacks to else part i.e. `decisionHandler(.allow, preferences)` on the first method because the `WKWebView` didn't recognise the link as a download, and trying to display it.

Please implement this method on `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationResponse.canShowMIMEType {
        decisionHandler(.allow) // In case of force download file; decisionHandler(.download)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.download)
    }
}
```

`navigationResponse.canShowMIMEType` will be false if the WKWebView realises it can't display the content.

If the `WKWebView` is trying to `show` the `pdf` file instead of `downloading` it, By replacing `.allow` by `.download` on the above method, you should be able to download file.